# I am trying to make a copy button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple copy button in javascript
but it is throwing me an error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'myInp.select')
```

When I click on copy  button

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 id="title">Copy to Clipboard - JAVA Script</h2>
    <input id=" myInp" type="text">
    <button id="btncopy">Copy</button>
</body>
<script>
    const myInp = document.getElementById("myInp");
    const btncopy = document.getElementById("btncopy");
    btncopy.onclick = function() {
        // selecting the text
        myInp.select();
    };
    document.execCommand("Copy");
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: are you trying to copy the value of the textbox??

Comment: Yes, I just type some random gibberish in my text box and then hit the copy button

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your main error was having a space in the id of myInp.

BTW The two lines below do the same thing. I've tested them both.

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(myInp.value);
document.execCommand("Copy");
```

```js
const myInp = document.getElementById("myInp");
const btncopy = document.getElementById("btncopy");

btncopy.onclick = function() {
  // selecting the text
  myInp.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(myInp.value);
  document.execCommand("Copy");
};
```

```html
<h2 id="title">Copy to Clipboard - JavaScript</h2>
<input id="myInp" type="text">
<button id="btncopy">Copy</button>
```